# Improper legend box size in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

I encountered a problem where the legend box is not automatically sized as the font size changes.

```
x = [1 4 6 8 0 2 4 7 8]
plot(x)
lngd = legend('Nov 5, 2010 09:00 - 09:01');
set(lngd, 'interpreter','latex', 'fontsize', 10);
```

generates the following graph

[image]

My **two problems** are

- The box size is too small. The words are out of box. I have tried `set(lngd, 'interpreter','latex', 'fontsize', 10, [0 0 10 10]);` to enlarge the box, but no luck.
- I wish to move the legend box to the right bottom. I have tried `set(lngd, 'southeast', 'interpreter','latex', 'fontsize', 10);`, but no luck.

How may I fix these two problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any particular reason that you use `'interpreter', 'latex'`? It seems to mess with the boxing of the legend for some MATLAB. You can try to manually change the legend box position and size by setting the `Position` variable.

```
x = [1 4 6 8 0 2 4 7 8]
plot(x)
lngd = legend('Nov 5, 2010 09:00 - 09:01');
set(lngd,  'fontsize', 10, 'interpreter','latex','Position', [0.55,0.15,0.35,0.08]);
```

The `Position` vector is `[left,bottom,width,height]` of the box in 0~1 range.

Comment: Yes, it is working, but I wonder whether there is a more automatic way.

Answer (score 2):

```
x = [1 4 6 8 0 2 4 7 8]
plot(x)
lngd = legend('Nov 5, 2010 09:00 - 09:01');
set(lngd, 'Location', 'SouthEast'); 
set(lngd, 'interpreter','latex', 'fontsize', 30);
```

Try this, it works fine in my matlab

Comment: The right part of the text is still out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

1. I cannot reproduce the problem on MATLAB R2010a, R2010b or R2013a. What version do you have?

   I have these defaults in my `startup.m`:

   ```
   set(0,...
       'DefaultFigurePaperPositionMode', 'auto',...
       'DefaultFigurePaperType'    , 'A4',...
       'DefaultFigurePaperUnits'   , 'centimeters',...
       'DefaultFigurePaperPosition', [3 3 8.4 10],...            
       'DefaultAxesFontsize'       , 14,...
       'DefaultTextColor'          , 'black',...
       'DefaultFigureRenderer'     , 'openGl',...
       'DefaultFigurePaperUnits'   , 'centimeters',...
       'DefaultFigurePaperPosition', [3 3 8.4 10],...
       'DefaultAxesFontsize'       , 14,...
       'DefaultAxesFontname'       , 'Times-Roman',...            
       'DefaultTextColor'          , 'black');
   ```

   Perhaps setting these changes things? (You'd be surprised how much some of these values affect sometimes...)
2. Use

   ```
   set(lgnd, 'location', 'southeast', ...);
   ```

Comment: I am using R2013a. The location issue can be resolved, but the text-out-of-box issue persists.